# C++ error: expected nested-name-specifier in Todd Veldhuizen's TMP Turing completeness proof

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm following [Todd Veldhuizen's TMP Turing completeness proof](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.3670) and when compiling the code with g++ I'm getting the following errors:

```
main.cpp:59:22: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘ApplyAction’
     typedef typename ApplyAction<next_state, action, Tape_Left, Tape_Current, Tape_Right,
main.cpp:59:22: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
main.cpp:59:33: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
     typedef typename ApplyAction<next_state, action, Tape_Left, Tape_Current, Tape_Right,
```

To sum it up, the objective of the proof is to simulate a simple Turing machine using templates, with the Machine operation consisting of receiving a string composed of characters 'a' and changing each one to '#'. I've made a direct translation of the code and highlighted the position of each section in my source:

```
#include <iostream>

/* States */

/* Alphabet */

/* Tape representation */

/* Transition Function */
/* q0 a -> (q1,#) */
/* q0 # -> (h,#) */
/* q1 a -> (q0,a) */
/* q1 # -> (q0,->) */

// The problem appears on the ApplyAction declaration    
/* Representation of a Configuration */
template<typename State,
        typename Tape_Left,
        typename Tape_Current,
        typename Tape_Right,
        template<typename Q, typename Sigma> class Delta>
struct Configuration {
    typedef typename Delta<State, Tape_Current>::next_state next_state;
    typedef typename Delta<State, Tape_Current>::action action;
    typedef typename ApplyAction<next_state, action, Tape_Left, Tape_Current, Tape_Right,
            Delta>::halted_configuration halted_configuration;
};

// ApplyAction is defined here
/* Default action: write to current tape cell */    
/* Move read head left */
/* Move read head right */
/*
* Move read head right when there are no nonblank characters
* to the right -- generate a new Blank symbol.
*/
/*
 * We halt by not declaring a halted_configuration.
 * This causes the compiler to display an error message
 * showing the halting configuration.
 */

int main() {    
    /*
    * An example "run": on the tape aaa starting in state q0
    */
    typedef Configuration<Q0, Nil, A, Pair<A,Pair<A,Nil> >,
    TransitionFunction>::halted_configuration Foo;
}
```

What does the error mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: Isn't that error the very one anticipated by the comment?

Comment: What is `ApplyAction`?  It has to be declared before `Configuration` tries to use it.

Comment: Sorry, which comment you mean? The anticipated result is a series of compiler error messages describing the turing machine computation, which is not the case here

Comment: Okay, since the error you copied is truncated I was unsure :)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That's the point, if you see the proof document `ApplyAction` is defined after `Configuration`

Comment: @Quentin should I post the full error output?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the paper is in explanatory order, not in source code order. At least a declaration of `ApplyAction` must be visible before its first use.

Comment: @Quentin I thought that was a possibility, but if you look at the `ApplyAction` definitions you will see that they use the `Configuration` struct, so swapping their definitions wield the error `Configuration does no name a type`

Comment: I made a pastebin with my code for you to try it [here](https://pastebin.com/sZCEPSQJ)

Comment: Nice, thanks! I can't test right now, but I think you just need to add a declaration of `Configuration` above `ApplyAction`.

Comment: @Quentin and do you now how would that declaration be? I tried it but with no success, I still don't know much about tmp sintax

Comment: Same as any other thing, the same but without a body: `template<typename State,
        typename Tape_Left,
        typename Tape_Current,
        typename Tape_Right,
        template<typename Q, typename Sigma> class Delta>
struct Configuration;`

Comment: @Quentin It worked! After also putting a `typename` before each `Configuration` use in the `ApplyAction` definitions, which yields [this code](https://pastebin.com/UnsYiXET). Would you like to turn this into an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Um, it's 3:40am here and I'm on my phone, so I will pass. Have fun with templates ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a nice discussion with @Quentin I found the solution to the problem. It turns out I had to declare the `ApplyAction` classes before defining the `Configuration` class, and to do so I had to add a prototype of the `Configuration` class before defining `ApplyAction`. Also, I had to add `typename` before each `Configuration` reference in `ApplyAction`:

```
/* Configuration prototype */
template<typename State, typename Tape_Left, typename Tape_Current,
        typename Tape_Right, template<typename Q, typename Sigma> class Delta>
struct Configuration;

/* ApplyAction definitions */

template<typename NextState, typename Action,
        typename Tape_Left, typename Tape_Current, typename Tape_Right,
        template<typename Q, typename Sigma> class Delta>
struct ApplyAction {
    typedef typename Configuration<NextState, Tape_Left,
            Action, Tape_Right, Delta>::halted_configuration halted_configuration;
};

template<typename NextState,
        typename Tape_Left, typename Tape_Current, typename Tape_Right,
        template<typename Q, typename Sigma> class Delta>
struct ApplyAction<NextState, Left, Tape_Left,
        Tape_Current, Tape_Right, Delta> {
    typedef typename Configuration<NextState,
            typename Tape_Left::tail,
            typename Tape_Left::head,
            Pair<Tape_Current, Tape_Right>,
            Delta>::halted_configuration
            halted_configuration;
};

template<typename NextState, typename Tape_Left,
        typename Tape_Current, typename Tape_Right,
        template<typename Q, typename Sigma> class Delta>
struct ApplyAction<NextState, Right, Tape_Left,
        Tape_Current, Tape_Right, Delta> {
    typedef typename Configuration<NextState,
            Pair<Tape_Current, Tape_Left>,
            typename Tape_Right::head,
            typename Tape_Right::tail,
            Delta>::halted_configuration
            halted_configuration;
};

template<typename NextState, typename Tape_Left,
        typename Tape_Current,
        template<typename Q, typename Sigma> class Delta>
struct ApplyAction<NextState, Right, Tape_Left,
        Tape_Current, Nil, Delta> {
    typedef typename Configuration<NextState,
            Pair<Tape_Current, Tape_Left>,
            Blank, Nil, Delta>::halted_configuration
            halted_configuration;
};

template<typename Action, typename Tape_Left,
        typename Tape_Current, typename Tape_Right,
        template<typename Q, typename Sigma> class Delta>
struct ApplyAction<Halt, Action, Tape_Left,
        Tape_Current, Tape_Right, Delta> {
    //
};

template<typename State,
        typename Tape_Left,
        typename Tape_Current,
        typename Tape_Right,
        template<typename Q, typename Sigma> class Delta>
struct Configuration {
    typedef typename Delta<State, Tape_Current>::next_state next_state;
    typedef typename Delta<State, Tape_Current>::action action;
    typedef typename ApplyAction<next_state, action, Tape_Left, Tape_Current, Tape_Right,
            Delta>::halted_configuration halted_configuration;
};
```